# How to show Range in the dialog window and retain formatting and auto-numbering

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I'm struggling to figure out how to show the `Range` text of Word document in a dialog window with retaining formatting and auto-numbering and do not modify source document at the same time. I was trying to use `RichTextBox` control and copy-paste `Range` into it, but it does not retain auto-numbering. I tried to create a copy of range using `Duplicate` property, but according to documentation it only allows me to change `Start` and `End` properties without affecting original object so when I call then method `ConvertNumbersToText` of `ListFormat` it does convert number to text in source document and therefore breaks the order of numbers in list. Is there any way to utilize Word's native functionality to display only small part of the document in a dialog window and be able to modify text right there with no pain?

Comment: Not really, no... What is the purpose of editing text in a dialog window instead of in the document, itself?

Comment: The main reason is to make it possible to show multiple pieces of the document at the same time with retaining the focus on a particular section of the document in main window. I have found the Split Window functionality which could probably help me to modify the document easily, but it doesn't allow me to see many pieces of the document at the same time what is kind of critical requirement.

Comment: About the only thing that occurs to me would be to transfer the content to a second ("scratch") document using Range.FormattedText, convert the numbers to text, put it in the dialog box then close the scratch document without saving. Any editing would have to be done in the main document, though. If the monitor is big enough, or multiple monitors are an option, there's the "New Window" and "Arrange All" options in the View menu (instead of splitting the window) which would give you an unlimited number of views (but with a full Word application window, Ribbon and all):

Comment: You can get the numbering into your dialogue without using ConvertNumbersToText, via  ListFormat.ListString, followed by the relevant text.